# "not an ELF file" on libudisks2.so.0 while apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and today while doing `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` I got this kind of messages:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudisks2.so.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudisks2.so.0.0.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
```

These messages were shown also when I was trying to update VirtualBox and because of these errors updating failed.

I've read answers to similiar questions and trying to reinstall the libudisks2 package, but when I pass `sudo apt-get purge libudisks2-0` command I was told that also these packages will be removed:

```
brasero* checkbox-converged* checkbox-gui* deja-dup-backend-gvfs*
gir1.2-udisks-2.0* gnome-applets* gnome-disk-utility*
gnome-session-flashback* gvfs* gvfs-backends* gvfs-daemons* gvfs-fuse*
libudisks2-0* nautilus* nautilus-sendto* nautilus-share*
plainbox-provider-checkbox* plainbox-provider-resource-generic*
python3-checkbox-support* software-center* ubuntu-desktop* udisks2*
usb-creator-common* usb-creator-gtk*
```

So I suppose it's not the best option.
Has someone the idea of fixing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purging is bad idea!

To be completely sure we need to determine which package contain both `libudisks2.so.0` on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libudisks2.so.0), here we get `libudisks2-0`.

So we can reinstall the package:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudisks2.so.0
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudisks2.so.0.0.0

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libudisks2-0
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple, but did resolve my problem :)